# Inline keyboard pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Необходимо прикрепить Inline клавиатуру к последнему сообщению
ПРИМЕР КОДА:

```py
  elif call.data == "Важные термины":
        keyboard_new = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        currencypair = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Валютные пары', callback_data='Валютные пары')
        keyboard_new.add(currencypair)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text=importantTerms_text)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text=currencyPair_text)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text=lotAndSpred_text)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text=leverageAndMargin_text)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text=takeProfitTimeProfit_text)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text=marginCall_text)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text=stopLossSupportLevel_text)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text=gep_text)
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text=continue_text,
                              reply_markup=keyboard_new)
```

Проблема в том, что идет замена активной Inline клавиатуры

Пример корректного результата - 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Проблема в том, что идет замена активной Inline клавиатуры

может потому что Вы используете `bot.edit_message_text` вместо `bot.send_message`?